# User cannot comment, so asks for clarification by editing someone else's answer

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Scenario: User A asks a question (properly, in the "Question" field):

> I am trying to do X with code `Y`, but it does Z instead. What is the problem?

User B then answers it (properly, in the "Answer" field):

> Your code has bugs. Use this code `Y1` instead.

So far so good. But what if user A wants to clarify something about the code? He doesn't have the privilege to comment. So he decides to edit the answer (!) with text asking for clarification. This is bad, but not the user's fault - the system forces him to find a fishy workaround for a legitimate action.

It gets worse - user B then approves (!) user A's change; now the answer belonging to user B contains a question that user A asked. User B then answers the inquiry in a comment.

All this mess was caused by the system not allowing user A to comment on the answer that belongs to user B. Does it have to be so stubborn? Why not allow user A to comment? The answer "belongs" to user A's question, so the same logic that allows user A to comment on his own question could allow him to comment on the answers too.

I am not sure I should add a link to the specific Q and A here. Will add it if people think it's relevant.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Even if you don't have the 50 reputation necessary to [comment *everywhere*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you can still comment on answers on your own question. So user A doesn't need to edit user B's answers at all.

> Please note that you can *always* comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions.

"any part of your questions" is a bit cryptic, but answers are considered part of a question.